# Unreadable html characters in the Oracle Apex

Tags: html, regex, oracle-apex

I have a regex code to validate character exceptions when the input is successful, the problem is there is one html character "€" which is not read on the page item apex after reloading the input and the validation message, in the validation message I have given the code "&#8364" so that it can be read, but for the page item itself I have not found a way.
[the "€" character immediately changes to "?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXQfe.png)

Comment: It is most likely a character set issue in either your database or the web server? Are they using `AL32UTF8`?

Comment: I don't think so, because I also tried to query the character in sql developer and it wasn't readable

Comment: What is the character set of your database?

Comment: I don't know, but is there any other way so that the character can be read in the apex text box, such as with a function or declare. if that could be the process where ?